# pandas merge rows into previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge all blank rows such as 4,5,6 into 3 and 8,9,10 into 7 and so on...

I tried this but getting wrong answer.

```
dataframe=dataframe.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
dataframe=dataframe[:-1].fillna(method='ffill')

final_data = dataframe[dataframe['Value Date'].notna()]
final_data = final_data.fillna(0)

x = final_data.groupby(['Booking','Debit','Credit', 'Balance'])['Text'].apply(','.join)
x = x.reset_index()
```

Help me with it.

Comment: please add your data as text, `print(df.head(25).to_dict())` paste the output into your queustion exactly as it's output.

Comment: @Manakin Done, Thank you for code to get it

Answer (score 2):

My solution starts as @Manakin, assuming the dict is called `data`:

```
Timestamp = pd.Timestamp
NaT = pd.NaT
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and then:

```
(df.groupby((df['Balance'] != '').cumsum())
    .agg(dict(dict.fromkeys(df,'first'), **{'Booking Text':', '.join}))
    )
```

produces

```
 Balance  Booking Date         Txn Date             Booking Text                                                                                                                                                 Value Date           Debit       Credit          Balance
---------  -------------------  -------------------  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -------------------  ----------  --------------  --------------
        1  2018-03-31 00:00:00  2018-03-31 00:00:00  Initial Balance                                                                                                                                              NaT                                              0.00
        2  2018-01-04 00:00:00  2018-01-04 00:00:00  VALUE DATED BALANCE BROUGHT FORWARD                                                                                                                          2018-01-04 00:00:00              180,431,640.00  180,431,640.00
        3  2018-06-04 00:00:00  2018-06-04 00:00:00  INTEREST-FIXED TERM LOAN, Contract No: 3001-AA18091ZN72C|Interest rate:, 0.810000%|Capital: 1,000,000,000.00|Period: 16.03.2018 -, 06.04.2018|Days: 21/360   2018-06-04 00:00:00  472,500.00                  179,959,140.00
        4  2018-06-04 00:00:00  2018-06-04 00:00:00  INTEREST-FIXED TERM LOAN, Contract No: 3001-AA1809166QNF|Interest rate:                                                                                      2018-06-04 00:00:00  315,000.00                  179,644,140.00
                                                     B anking, 0.810000%|Capital: 1,000,000,000.00|Period: 23.03.2018 -, 06.04.2018|Days: 14/360
        5  2018-06-04 00:00:00  2018-06-04 00:00:00  FOREX SPOT, EUR/JPY 130.7271                                                                                                                                 2018-06-04 00:00:00              472,500.00      180,116,640.00
        6  2018-06-04 00:00:00  2018-06-04 00:00:00  FOREX SPOT, EUR/JPY 130.7021                                                                                                                                 2018-06-04 00:00:00              315,000.00      180,431,640.00
        7  2018-09-04 00:00:00  2018-09-04 00:00:00  INTEREST-FIXED TERM LOAN, Contract No: 3001-AA18091NTT8N|Interest rate:, 0.810000%|Capital: 500,000,000.00|Period: 26.03.2018 -, 09.04.2018|Days: 14/360, ,  2018-09-04 00:00:00  157,500.00                  180,274,140.00
        8  2018-09-04 00:00:00  2018-09-04 00:00:00  FOREX SPOT                                                                                                                                                   2018-09-04 00:00:00              157,500.00      180,431,640.00
                                                     EUR/JPY 131.1407
        9  2018-10-04 00:00:00  2018-10-04 00:00:00  INTEREST-FIXED TERM LOAN, , Contract No: 3001-AA18091NL9XG|Interest rate:, 0.810000%|Capital: 500,000,000.00|Period: 27.03.2018 -                            2018-10-04 00:00:00  157,500.00                  180,274,140.00
                                                     10.04.2018|Days: 14/360
```

Here we groupby rows that have 'Balance' empty to the row above, and then apply `first` aggregation to all columns except to `'Booking Text'` where we concatenate strings together

Comment: getting error `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 7, placement implies 1`. Can you help me with your full code

Comment: This _is_ my full code. Which version of Python and of Pandas are you using? also can you put the whole error trace here

Comment: I'm using `python3.6` and `pandas==1.1.4`, I won't be able to put whole error on comment as it is longer than comment length.

Comment: hmm. and you are executing it right after you executed `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` where `data` is the dictionary from your question, `data = {'Booking Date': {1: Timestamp('2018-03-31 00:00:00'), 2: ....`

Comment: Sorry my bad I got the answer I did something wrong. The problem right now is there is unwanted 1st row as value only `Balance`. How do I remove that?

Comment: not sure what you mean, the whole first _column_ labeled Balance, or the first _row_ with index 1. If the former add `.reset_index(drop=True)` at the end, if the latter add `.drop(1)`

Comment: There is unwanted column called `Balance` which has index which I don't want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225429/discussion-between-piterbarg-and-avanish-tiwari).

Answer (score 1):

From your dict, assuming it's called `d`

we can create a new `key` to groupby and join the string columns.

```
import pandas as pd

Timestamp = pd.Timestamp, NaT = pd.NaT

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)


df['key'] = (df['Booking Date'].isnull() & df['Booking Date'].shift(1).isnull()==False).astype(int).cumsum()


s = df.groupby('key')['Booking Text'].agg(' '.join)
s.index = s.index - 1

df1 = df.dropna(subset=['Booking Date']).copy()
df1['Booking Text'] = df1['Booking Text'] + ' ' + df1.pop('key').map(s)
```

---

```
print(df1)

  Booking Date   Txn Date                                       Booking Text  \
1    2018-03-31 2018-03-31  Initial Balance VALUE DATED BALANCE BROUGHT FO...   
2    2018-01-04 2018-01-04  VALUE DATED BALANCE BROUGHT FORWARD INTEREST-F...   
3    2018-06-04 2018-06-04  INTEREST-FIXED TERM LOAN Contract No: 3001-AA1...   
7    2018-06-04 2018-06-04  INTEREST-FIXED TERM LOAN Contract No: 3001-AA1...   
11   2018-06-04 2018-06-04                        FOREX SPOT EUR/JPY 130.7271   
13   2018-06-04 2018-06-04                        FOREX SPOT EUR/JPY 130.7021   
15   2018-09-04 2018-09-04  INTEREST-FIXED TERM LOAN Contract No: 3001-AA1...   
21   2018-09-04 2018-09-04  FOREX SPOT\nEUR/JPY 131.1407 INTEREST-FIXED TE...   
22   2018-10-04 2018-10-04  INTEREST-FIXED TERM LOAN  Contract No: 3001-AA...   

   Value Date       Debit          Credit         Balance  
1         NaT                                        0.00  
2  2018-01-04              180,431,640.00  180,431,640.00  
3  2018-06-04  472,500.00                  179,959,140.00  
7  2018-06-04  315,000.00                  179,644,140.00  
11 2018-06-04                  472,500.00  180,116,640.00  
13 2018-06-04                  315,000.00  180,431,640.00  
15 2018-09-04  157,500.00                  180,274,140.00  
21 2018-09-04                  157,500.00  180,431,640.00  
22 2018-10-04  157,500.00                  180,274,140.00
```

Comment: There is unwanted column index. Also if you see row 1 column `Booking Text` is also merged which I don't want to merge. I just want to merge only those rows which has only `Booking Text`into row above it that has data such as `Balance`.